# PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC creating java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException on RedHat 6.4

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

We have an application that uses `Bouncy Castle` to encrypt data using `PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC` algorithm. It works fine on `Ubuntu` running `OpenJDK 1.7`. But when when we move it to `RedHat 6.4` also running `OpenJDK 1.7`, we get the following exception:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Any thoughts on what could be causing this. How can we add `PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC` algorithm to `RedHat 6.4`?

**p.s.** the application is running in `JBoss`.

```
private String cryptoAlgorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC";

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

// load passPhrase from configured external file to char array.
char[] passPhrase = null;
try {
    passPhrase = loadPassPhrase(passPhraseFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw BeanHelper.logException(LOG, methodName, new EJBException("The file not found: " + passPhraseFile, e));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw BeanHelper.logException(LOG, methodName, new EJBException("Error in reading file: " + passPhraseFile, e));
}

PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase);

try {
    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(cryptoAlgorithm);
    SecretKey newSecretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    return newSecretKey;
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw BeanHelper.logException(LOG, methodName, new EJBException("The algorithm is not found: " + cryptoAlgorithm, e));
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    throw BeanHelper.logException(LOG, methodName, new EJBException("The key spec is invalid", e));
}
```

(**On RH 6.4**)

```
#java -version
java version "1.7.0_19"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.9.1.el6_4-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

(**On Ubuntu 12.04**)

```
#java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can your RedHat code find other Bouncy Castle code?

Comment: yes, i can use "PBEWithMD5AndDES" with bouncy castle on redhat fine.

Comment: Is letter case the problem?  Can you find `PBEWithSHA256And128BITAES-CBC-BC`.  What does the BC manual say?

Comment: no. i have already tried with PBEWithSHA256And128BITAES-CBC-BC

Comment: Is it all or part of the `-CBC-BC` at the end?  The one that worked didn't have that bit.

Comment: i tried PBEWithSHA256And128BITAES as well. same error.

Comment: Can you compare both of the `$jre-home\lib\security` directories,  and if they look the same, the content of *_policy jars?

Comment: Same version of the Bouncy Castle library on both systems?

Comment: the content of the files in jre-home\lib\security look similar, but not exactly same. can you please tell what I am looking for?

Comment: Could you please provide us with the complete stacktrace?

Comment: What versions of Bouncy Castle are you using on each system?

Comment: how do i check the version of the bouncy castle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have the BouncyCastle provider JAR (e.g. bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar) in your classpath?

I tested your scenario with a minimal CentOS 6.4 (64-bit) installation, OpenJDK 1.7 and BouncyCastle 1.49, and found no issues with it.

I placed the JAR in the JRE lib/ext directory:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/jre/lib/ext
```

Comment: it is on the machine where ear file was compiled. does have to exist on the jboss server as well?

Comment: If the BouncyCastle JAR is not within the EAR, then you need to copy the JAR to the JBoss machine. In fact I would recommend to not put the JAR in the EAR but to place it in the appropriate jre/lib/ext folder (see example path above).

Comment: Try and remove the JAR from the EAR and put it in the appropriate JBoss profile's lib directory (e.g. server/default/lib) or in the said JRE lib/ext directory . Also make sure JBoss isn't already packing (a possibly differing version of) BouncyCastle.

Answer (score 2):

I try to confirm your issue and looks like problem in your environment. Here is sample of code i successfully run on clean OpenJDK 1.7, 1.6, Oracle JDK 1.7 and 1.6

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_19"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.9.1.el6_4-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode):
```

Command line: `java -cp  bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar:. Test`

Output: `OK`

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String cryptoAlgorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC";
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        char[] passPhrase = null;
        passPhrase = "12321".toCharArray();
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase);
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(cryptoAlgorithm, "BC");
            SecretKey newSecretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            assert newSecretKey != null;
            System.out.println("OK");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("The algorithm is not found: " + cryptoAlgorithm);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            System.out.println("The key spec is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Try to run that program on your environment. BouncyCastle jar you can download from here http://downloads.bouncycastle.org/java/bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar

Answer (score 0):

I guess the order of the security providers is different in both environments.

```
for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders())
{
    System.out.println("Name: " + provider.getName() + " Version: " + provider.getVersion());
}
```

you can try to insert the bouncy castle provider at a specific position in the chain of providers. Here for example at the first position, if no other security provider is used this should not lead into problems.

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

the use of a specific provider for an algorithm is not recommended

```
SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(cryptoAlgorithm, provider)
```

see: [Java ™ Cryptography Architecture(JCA) Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderImplReq)

Comment: That cannot be it, as the providers will be questioned for the implemented algorithm strings. The whole bunch of providers will be tested unless a specific provider is given.

Comment: For sure it **should** not be. But it doesn't work. And as I said "I guess". So at least it would be worth to first check the order of registered providers and then check if a manual insert of BC at first position would fix it. If not follow-up the investigation. But to find the issue you need to start at some point. ;-)
And those above checks are done quick and if they are not the solution at least you can remove them from the list of possibilities.