# NoSuchAlgorithmException PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm working on a Java cross-platform client application that would use PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC from Bouncy Castle API encryption to store sensitive information in local files.

The following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
        for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices()) {
            System.out.println(provider.getName() + ": " + service.getAlgorithm());
        }
    }

    SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC");
}
```

gives me the following exception :

```
SUN: NativePRNG
SUN: SHA1PRNG
SUN: SHA1withDSA
[...]
BC: PBEWITHSHAAND192BITAES-CBC-BC
BC: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC
BC: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
BC: PBEWITHSHA256AND192BITAES-CBC-BC
BC: PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC
BC: DESMAC
[...]
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC SecretKeyFactory not available
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at TestBouncyCastle.main(TestBouncyCastle.java:47)
```

That's strange since PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC is listed as an available service.

On the Bouncy Castle wiki, there is this [note](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) :

> Note: to make full use of the provider you *must* install the
>   unlimited policy files in the JVM you are using - these can be
>   downloaded from http://java.sun.com.

If I understand correctly, I need to install a file in the client JRE. And I would like to avoid providing a JRE with the application. Is there a way around?

Thanks!

Comment: Just because `PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC` algorithm name is supported in no way means that `PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES` is supported too.

Comment: And also what is your question? The title mentions the name of unsupported algorithm, the body provides the list of supported algorithm and the one in the title is not among them. And then you ask something inconsistent about not wanting to provide a JRE with the application.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I was trying a suggestion in a comment found in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857723/pbewithsha256and128bitaes-cbc-bc-creating-java-security-nosuchalgorithmexception
and forgot to put -CBC-CB back. I have the same exception with PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC. I'll fix the question.

Comment: Please recheck - I am getting proper `SecretKeyFactory` instance from your code with BC 1.50. 128 bit keys should be allowed even under default restricted crypto, so that should not be a problem either.

Comment: Do you have the unlimited policy files installed in the JVM you are using? I would like to know if there is a way around that or the possibility to install this component dynamically.

Comment: I tested with and without unlimited crypto. Your exact code works and returns a `SecretKeyFactory` instance.

Comment: Weird, it does not work on my side... I'm using Java 6 on Mac OS X: java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)

Comment: And it does not look like a classpath issue, since the BC services are listed. I'm using: bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar